# Define an arbitrary Field on a django-rest-framework Serializer that doesn't exist on the Django Model

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd want to define an arbitrary `Field` on a **django-rest-framework** `Serializer` that doesn't exist on the Django `Model`.

My code looks like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    foo = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'foo')

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

This code fails with:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `key` on serializer `PersonSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Person` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Person' object has no attribute 'key'.
```

But... If I adjust the `Person` class to this:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Then I don't get the error, and I can POST the data.

I don't like the idea of creating a dummy method on the `Person` class to get around this error.  Is there a **django-rest-framework** way to alleviate this error that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, using a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    ...

    def get_foo(self, obj):
        return 'the foo'
```

Then the logic about how to serialize the additional field just lives on the serializer itself, however it does have access to the instance, if required, through `obj`.